# Malloc double pointer

Tags: c

My function prototype should look like this:

```
void double_min_max(int **range, int min, int max)
```

I have to fill 'range' with number from min to max.

I don't know how to malloc the double pointer and how to assign every element the number min.

```
void    double_min_max(int **range, int min, int max)
{
    range = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int)* 10);
    int i = 0;
        while (min < max)
        {
        **range[i] = min;
        i++;
        min++;
    }
}
```

Comment: range = (int **) malloc(sizeof(max-min));

Comment: Nobody here will write the code for you. If you go to www.google.com and type in the title of your question, "malloc double pointer", there are plenty of examples regarding the allocation part.

Comment: Then read how to use malloc and what a for loop is. @Rajeshkumar you this will allocate just the difference between min and max in bytes, also avoid casting the result from malloc.

Comment: What is your code so far, you should show your effort so that we can help you at a specific problem.

Comment: With this declaration, you should **pass** a pointer from calling code. 
 Then just do `size_t size = max - min + 1; *range = malloc(size * sizeof **range);`

Comment: What's the use of the i variable and why *10?

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/iS0kDY)

Comment: @AndreKampling surely. Added.

Comment: In C, do not cast the result of a call to `malloc()`, `realloc()`, or `calloc()` - it is unnecessary and potentially masks the serious error of a missing prototype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, let's spot the errors:

```
void double_min_max(int **range, int min, int max)
{
    range = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int)* 10);
```

The cast with malloc is unnecessary and could even [lead to problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2371524). Don't do this.

Then you want to assign to `*range`, not to `range`. `range` is local to your function (all arguments are passed *by value* in C), so modifying it will never have any effect visible to the calling code. When you call this function, you should pass a *pointer to a pointer*, so the pointer can be modified by the function through `*range`.

Finally, this should be obvious, but you should **calculate** the required size from your `min` and `max`. The `10` is just a ... uhm ... *very rough guess*. Not a good idea.

```
    int i = 0;
        while (min < max)
        {
        **range[i] = min;
```

This is wrong. `[]` does dereference the pointer, so you have three levels of dereferencing here. But it's only a *pointer to pointer*, not *pointer to pointer to pointer*. Also, indexing precedes the normal dereference, not what you want. Use `(*range)[i]` instead.

```
        i++;
        min++;
    }
}
```

A sensible implementation could look like this:

```
size_t double_min_max(int **range, int min, int max)
{
    // check for valid input
    if (min > max) return 0;

    // calculate required size
    size_t size = max - min + 1;

    *range = malloc(size * sizeof **range);

    // check allocation succeeded:
    if (!*range) return 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        (*range)[i] = min++;
    }
    return size;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
int *range;
size_t result = double_min_max(&range, 10, 20);

// result should now be 11, the size of the array `range` points to

// when done:
free(range);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `**range = malloc...`, you actually access/assign the first integer value to which the "pointer to pointer to int" (this is what `int **range` denotes) points. 
This should be `*range = malloc...` instead. Further, `**range[i]` is illegal, as `**range` is an integer value, not an array or pointer, such that the  `**range[i]=min` dereferences an integer value (which in this context is illegal/undefined behaviour). It should rather be `*range[i]=min`.

So the complete code including some necessary checks, the use of the function and also the use of the result could look as follows:

```
int double_min_max(int **range, int min, int max) {

    // range is a pointer PPI to a pointer PI pointing to one (or more consecutive) integers I
    // *range is the "value" of PI, i.e. the pointer to the memory block representing the sequence of integers

    if (min >= max)  // check if the range is valid
        return 0;

    if (!range) // check if you may assign a value to *range
        return 0;

    int size = max - min;
    int *intArray = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    if (!intArray) // did malloc fail?
        return 0;

    // fill the range
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        intArray[i] = min+i;
    }

    // let *range point to the malloced and filled array
    *range = intArray;

    // return the size of the array.
    return size;
}

int main() {

    int *myRange = NULL;
    int size = double_min_max(&myRange, -30, -10);

    if (size && myRange) {
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            printf("%d ", myRange[i]);
        }
        free(myRange);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _It should rather be `*range[i]=anIntValue`._ I think that this will mislead OP.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Uups, thanks!